How can i understand when unsubscribing is happening a toSignal(x) in a service
private xSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);    
public $x = this.xSubject.asObservable();   
public xSignal = toSignal(this.xSubject, { requireSync: true });

i need to use signals but im not really sure using with http and reactive context

toSignal is already a subscription. it will unsubscribe with the corresponding injector death. i.e. if this code is inside of a service that is provideIn: 'root' it will only unsubscribe if the application is destroyed

TLDR; When the service is destroyed the subscription is unsubscribed
From the source code to_signal.ts
When we use a toSignal. Internally it gets the destroyRef injector of the service/component you are using it on.
const cleanupRef = requiresCleanup
    ? options?.injector?.get(DestroyRef) ?? inject(DestroyRef)
    : null;

Remember inject can only be used at the root level of the component and not inside hooks or functions, so the use of inject is the reason we cannot use signals inside functions or hooks.
In the docs destroyRef

DestroyRef lets you set callbacks to run for any cleanup or destruction behavior. The scope of this destruction depends on where DestroyRef is injected. If DestroyRef is injected in a component or directive, the callbacks run when that component or directive is destroyed. Otherwise the callbacks run when a corresponding injector is destroyed.

After this is fetched, they call the unsubscribe on the onDestroy callback
// Unsubscribe when the current context is destroyed, if requested.
cleanupRef?.onDestroy(sub.unsubscribe.bind(sub));

So to sum up, when the component/service gets destroyed the toSignal gets unsubscribed.
Apart from this you have two other options.
/**
   * `Injector` which will provide the `DestroyRef` used to clean up the Observable subscription.
   *
   * If this is not provided, a `DestroyRef` will be retrieved from the current [injection
   * context](guide/di/dependency-injection-context), unless manual cleanup is requested.
   */
  injector?: Injector;

  /**
   * Whether the subscription should be automatically cleaned up (via `DestroyRef`) when
   * `toSignal`'s creation context is destroyed.
   *
   * If manual cleanup is enabled, then `DestroyRef` is not used, and the subscription will persist
   * until the `Observable` itself completes.
   */
  manualCleanup?: boolean;

